# Getting error 'Table,View Or Sequence reference 'EMPLOYEES.EMP_NAME' not allowed in this context'

Tags: plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, plsqldeveloper

```
create table Employees (emp_id number, emp_name varchar2(50), salary number, department_id number, DESIGNATION varchar2(50), DEVELOPED_TESTED varchar2(50)) ;

insert into Employees values(1,'ALex',10000,10,'Developer','VLC');
insert into Employees values(2,'Duplex',20000,20,'Developer','VLC');
insert into Employees values(3,'Charles',30000,30,'Tester','Tested_VLC');
insert into Employees values(4,'Demon',40000,40,'Tester ','Tested_VLC');
insert into employees values(5,'Chaem',5000,50,'Developer','');
```

Requirement :

I want to return 2 if the designation is 'Developer' and developed_tested column is null. But in the output I am getting null and NOT 2. Can you please check on this.

Code :

```
        create or replace FUNCTION calculate_royalty (
    i_empno IN NUMBER
    
) RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
  l_employee employees%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN 
  SELECT *
    INTO l_employee
    FROM
        employees
    WHERE  emp_id = i_empno; 
  IF l_employee.designation = 'Developer' THEN
    RETURN l_employee.developed_tested;
  ELSIF l_employee.designation = 'Developer' and l_employee.developed_tested is null THEN 
    RETURN 2;
  ELSE
    RETURN 1;
  END IF;
  
EXCEPTION WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
  RETURN 0;
END ;
```

select CALCULATE_ROYALTY(5) from dual;  -- Output coming as NULL but it should be 2 ideally.

Comment: There is no "royalty" column in your test script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just select the entire row into a variable, no need to use a count. Use the `NO_DATA_FOUND` exception to handle the case of user does not exist.

Your question mentions some functionality related to the "royalty" column. That is missing from your test case but it should be a piece of cake to modify code below so it caters to all your needs.

```
create or replace FUNCTION calculate_royalty (
    empno_i IN NUMBER
    -- don't use column names as names of input parameters, that is a recipe for disaster. Use prefix/suffix.
) RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
  lv_count NUMBER;
  l_employee employees%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN 
  SELECT *
    INTO l_employee
    FROM
        employees
    WHERE  emp_id = empno_i; 
  IF l_employee.designation = 'Developer' THEN
    RETURN l_employee.salary;
  ELSE
    RETURN 1;
  END IF;
  -- dbms_output just sends data to a buffer that you then print to the console. it cannot be used as a return value.
  --  RETURN dbms_output.put_line('Emp Name :'...
  
-- elsif needs to be followed by an expression. It cannot be followed by a RETURN keyword. Use "ELSE" instead if there is no condition.
-- elsif return 1;
EXCEPTION WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
  RETURN 0;
END ;
/

set serveroutput on size 999999
clear screen
BEGIN
  dbms_output.put_line('output for Developer: '|| calculate_royalty(EMPNO_I => 2));
  dbms_output.put_line('output for no Developer: '|| calculate_royalty(EMPNO_I => 3));
  dbms_output.put_line('output for non-existing user: '|| calculate_royalty(EMPNO_I => 10));
END;

output for Developer: 20000
output for no Developer: 1
output for non-existing user: 0


PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Comment: Thanks but can you please let me know why it is not returning 2 for the last condition where designation is Developer and Developed_tested column is null. It is giving me null instead of 2. I have edited the changes in the original question

Comment: I suggest you study my code and see if you can edit it yourself to return 2 under those conditions. After all you're learning pl/sql so the more code you write yourself the more you're learn.

Comment: Done few modifications in the code but still it is not returning 2

Comment: Logical error. 1st condition yields true so other conditions are not tested anymore. Put most restrictive condition ( the one that returns 2 ) before less restrictive condition (the one returning developer_tested) and it should work. You could also put dbms_output statements to see which condition is satisfied.